# add data found in another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R programming and I have the following question.

I have two dataframes, the first one has a minimum and maximum time for an Id.
For the second dataframe, each record represents a transaction and is given at a specific time.

I need in a third dataframe to add the number of transactions of the second dataframe taking into account the time of the transaction (HourTRX) within the range of minimum and maximum hours of the first dataframe. Additionally, I appreciate if someone can tell me how I could pass these hours from character to time data type.

```r
df1     
        
Id  HourMIN HourMAX
A90 06:00:00    06:25:00
A91 08:00:00    08:30:00



df2     
        
Id  HourTRX Transaction
A90 06:00:00    1
A90 06:10:00    1
A90 06:25:00    1
A91 08:00:00    1
A91 08:05:00    1
A91 08:15:00    1
A91 08:25:00    1
A91 08:30:00    1


expected result         
            
Id  HourMIN HourMAX Quantity Transaction
A90 06:00:00    06:25:00    3
A91 08:00:00    08:30:00    5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to a `dplyr` based approach you could use a `left_join` combined with a `filter` and finally aggregating everything using `summarise`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "Id") %>% 
  group_by(Id, HourMIN, HourMAX) %>% 
  filter(HourTRX >= HourMIN, HourTRX <= HourMAX) %>% 
  summarise(Quantity_Transaction = sum(Transaction), .groups = "drop")
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Id    HourMIN HourMAX Quantity_Transaction
  <chr> <time>  <time>                 <dbl>
1 A90   06:00   06:25                      3
2 A91   08:00   08:30                      5
```